# How to get bean definitions in Eclipse SWT Wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am developing a SWT component in which there is a child component through which user can view the Spring reference and can change the Spring bean definition, property etc..

I am facing 2 issues:

1. If the defintion of bean is defined in some other Spring XML rather than the selected Spring file, then how to proceed.
2. How to fetch source code of class (for preview) from defined `beanClass` e.g. `com.xyz.abc.def.Foo`.

Comment: your question is not quite clear. Can you give more details as to what exactly in eclipse that you are unable to do to achieve this?

Comment: If the project contains 100 of spring file.. Whether i have to parse each file for finding the bean definition. or there is any way to look up...

Answer (score 0):

For getting the info from the spring xmls, you have to do some parsing, there is no beating around that. However you could use O/X Mappers to simplify this process http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html

Answer (score 0):

As codejammer said, you will have to parse all xml files and possibly also included files through different mechanisms. The safest would be to use Spring's own classes to deal with it. More specifically, see `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`[1] for reading and using a, possible custom, implementation of `BeanDefinitionRegistry`[2] for holding a map of your valid beans.

The second problem of loading the source for a class, that is as easy as changing the class' packet name to a fully qualified path: `com.xyz.abc.def.Foo` -> `com/xyz/abc/def/Foo.java`

1. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanDefinitionReader.html
2. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry.html